# Where is the Vanguard Armory?

Tags: destiny

In Destiny, if you pre-ordered, you get "early access to the Vanguard Armory."  Where is this, and what benefits does it impart upon the player?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Vanguard Armory is by the shipwright on the Tower. Go to the right when you first spawn and it's down that hallway.

The early access thing is a series of level 10 items that vary depending on your class. They're pretty good but by no means super amazing. When I hit level 10 I had only one gear piece that I bought there.

Note: You can talk to the robots hanging out in the Tower to see a map of the area. You can also use the Destiny Companion App to have a map and do other cool things like mess with your gear and read the grimoire cards.

Comment: You can actually start buying them at level 5 and they will scale up to level 10 the next time the store resets its counter after you've hit 10. They're definitely better at level 5 than anything else I picked up on Earth in drops.

Comment: Oh thanks for adding that, I had no idea. Guess I didn't hit the store until level 10.

Answer (score 2):

*[Disclaimer: I have not played Destiny. All information in this post is gained through secondary sources.]*

According to the official website, the Vanguard Armory grants access to [upgraded weapons](http://www.destinythegame.com/au/en/wheretobuy/vanguard-armory). If you pre-ordered, you should find several vendors around the game that you can use [Glimmer](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Glimmer) (the game's currency) to purchase. One of these vendors is located near the [shipwright](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2fupy6/vanguard_armory_where_is_it/).

Although the official website only lists flavour texts for the "upgraded weapons" the Vanguard Armory gives, we can find more details about these weapons by looking them up on the Destiny wiki. For instance, one of the weapons the Armory gives is the [Carte Blanche S.1](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Carte_Blanche_S.1), which is supposedly pretty powerful. 67 damage sounds like a lot I suppose, compared to the 36 of the [standard rifles](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Shingen-B).

Note that Bungie's website says at the bottom:

> Access to Vanguard Armory can also be attained through gameplay.

This probably means that the Vanguard Armory weapons can also be found if you do not preorder, but they will more difficult to find.

Comment: I'm not sure that the weapons are otherwise available, but I do know they not particularly overpowered. While they have slightly higher damage than others of their level they also don't have any special abilities like other weapons you'll find by then. Overall it's nice to have access to but not a game changer.